# What's this layout, any example about this one?

Tags: android-layout

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iCM6GlT-iAXxNWw7qAt165Q1PVWhMrSp

What's loading(blur) and then show icon layout?

How to create one like this?

Comment: search about shimmer animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start checking Shimmer effect. This help you showing any item layout structure as a placeholder while you are doing some extra work (or loading something)

**Result:**

[image: 1]]

**How to do it:**

First, add facebook Shimmer library to **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
}
```

Then create you **placeholder_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="#dddddd" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#dddddd" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next, in your activity layout, add the **ShimmerFrameLayout** with your placeholders.

```
<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    shimmer:duration="800">

    <!-- Adding 7 rows of placeholders -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />
        <include layout="@layout/data_placeholder_layout" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Finally manage when to show or hide the **ShimmerFrameLayout** in your **Activity/Fragment** class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShimmerFrameLayout mShimmerViewContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mShimmerViewContainer = findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);

        // Stop Shimmer effect whenever you want. e.g. when data 
        // is received from web service 
        mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
        mShimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mShimmerViewContainer.startShimmerAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Don't forget to start and stop the component when the view is no longer visible. Use **onResume()** and **onPause()**

Hope this helps you.

Source: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-design-shimmer-effect-fa7f74c68a93